# Convert ugly string to a date

Tags: sas

I have some datetimes in data set as ugly strings.

Example: "Saturday  14 Jan 2017 00:00:00"

I would like to convert this into a date, e.g. 2017JAN14

Any simpler solution then going down the regular expression route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want exactly `yyyymmmdd` then you'll need to create your own format to do that, but you're happy with a builtin then the following should do. Just skip the day of the week and convert the rest using an informat:

```
data _null_;
mytxtdate = "Saturday 14 Jan 2017 00:00:00";
mydate = input(compress(substr(mytxtdate,index(mytxtdate,' '))),date9.);
format mydate yymmdd10.;
put _all_;
run;
```

This certainly is awkward. I'd be interested to know if there's a way of doing this as a one-liner using fewer than 4 data step functions. The logic here is:

- Skip to the first space using `index`.
- Remove all spaces in the string from that point onwards using `substr` and `compress`
- Input as a SAS date using the `date9.` informat, which will look at just the first 9 characters of the resulting string and ignore the rest.

Comment: Your code outputs the date as "2002-01-14", which is the wrong year. The month and date are fine? http://imgur.com/kjDaQ4z

Comment: This worked great. Thank you! I will tweak around with it and update if I find something shorter.